# Connecting arduino to a PC

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi

How would you send data wirelessly from arduino uno to a pc?

I know you can connect wifi shield / wifi breakout to arduino and use that, but what other ways are there and how practical would they be?

Comment: Almost everything else would require an additional adapter.

Comment: Laptops and smartphones come with built-in bluetooth, maybe use that?

Comment: You would need a bluetooth extension to the arduino this one would work over serial http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_trksid=p5197.m570.l1313&_nkw=bluetooth+serial+module&_sacat=0&_from=R40. Then you would need to do bluetooth programming on your laptop or smartphone. You can look this up for the specific system you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options. One is Bluetooth and another is [nRF24L01+ 2.4GHz Wireless Transceiver](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/22460/13281). I love the `nRF24L01+`. They are cheap and there are tons of examples online.

The concept with the `nRF24L01+` is to connect the RF24 to a Ft232rl Ftdi Usb to Ttl Serial Adapter. The Ft232rl  connects to your PC. Most modern computer languages support communicating via Serial. This is the way to go.

Google around for a ton of tutorials

Comment: Could you describe how you can plug the nRF24L01+ to a PC? This is what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @jfpoilpret - See my reside answer